# Java API code with Spring

Tags: java, api, spring

Model:

```
public class UserBean {     
    @JsonProperty
    private String userId;          
    @JsonProperty
    private int limit;      
    @JsonProperty
    private int page;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public int getLimit() {
        return limit;
    }
    public void setLimit(int limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }
    public int getPage() {
        return page;
    }
    public void setPage(int page) {
        this.page = page;
    }
}

public class ResponseJSON {
    private Map<String, Object> response = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>(); 
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        response.put("status", status);
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        response.put("message", message);
    }       
    public void add(String key, Object value) {
        response.put(key, value);
    }       
    public Map<String, Object> get() {
        return this.response;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/products", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object getProductListByUser(@RequestBody UserBean userBean) {
    ResponseJSON responseJSON = new ResponseJSON();
    try {
        List<Object> result = userRepository.getProductListByUser(userBean);
        int resultCount = result.size();

        List<Object> productList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < resultCount; i++) {
            ProductInfo product = (ProductInfo) result.get(i);

            Map<String, Object> productInfo = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();                  
            productInfo.put("id", product.getId());
            productInfo.put("title", product.getTitle());
            productInfo.put("description", product.getDescription());
            productInfo.put("iconImage", product.getIconImage());               
            productInfo.put("updateDatetime", product.getUpdateDatetime());
            productInfo.put("createDatetime", product.getCreateDatetime());
            productList.add(productInfo);
        }

        responseJSON.setStatus(Constants.SUCCESS);
        responseJSON.add("items", productList); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        responseJSON.setStatus(Constants.FAIL);
        responseJSON.setMessage(e.getMessage());
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }

    return responseJSON.get();
}
```

Repository:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional
public List<Object> getProductListByUser(UserBean userBean) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(ProductInfo.class, "product")
        .createAlias("product.productOptions", "options", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
        .add(Restrictions.eq("product.userId", userBean.getUserId()))
        .addOrder(Order.asc("productOptions.size"))
        .setFirstResult((userBean.getPage() - 1) * userBean.getLimit());
        .setMaxResults(userBean.getLimit());

    return criteria.list(); 
}
```

I'm developing some back-end APIs.
This API returns product lists of some user.
Purpose of this API is returning result of JSON data. 
So, I get datas from repository and assign to `ResponseJSON` object in the controller.
Is this approach efficient or not? Which way is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to follow the `getProductListByUser` method if you use two `ResponseJSON` instance. One for normal execution and one for the exceptional cases:

```
try {
    ...

    final ResponseJSON responseJSON = new ResponseJSON();
    ...

    responseJSON.setStatus(Constants.SUCCESS);
    responseJSON.add("items", productList); 
    return responseJSON.get();
} catch (final Exception e) {
    final ResponseJSON responseJSON = new ResponseJSON();
    responseJSON.setStatus(Constants.FAIL);
    responseJSON.setMessage(e.getMessage());
    logger.error(e.getMessage());
    return responseJSON.get();
}
```

It also ensures that nobody modifies accidentally the exception case result in the `try` block and there isn't any incomplete `ProductInfo` data in the error response.